# Using a Factory to create a Strategy

Tags: java, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I have the following Strategy Pattern implemented:

```
public abstract class RetrievalStrategy {
    public abstract List<MyObject> retrieve();
}

public class LimitRetrievalStrategy extends RetrievalStrategy {
    public int limit;
    public LimitRetrievalStrategy(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public List<MyObject> retrieve() {
        // fill up the list and return it, limiting to 'limit' results
        return new ArrayList<MyObject>(limit);
    }
}

public class SpeedRetrievalStrategy extends RetrievalStrategy {
    public int speed;
    public SpeedRetrievalStrategy(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public List<MyObject> retrieve() {
        // do something with the speed and return list again
        return new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }
}
```

My client application receives either a speed or a limit (and perhaps other parameters) from the user. I want to create a factory class that will return the proper strategy based on parameters that have a value and parameters that don't. I don't want the client the decide which Strategy should be returned. Should the factory `createStrategy(params)` method then have `if` statements for each parameter and depending on the different combinations (imagine there are other Strategy classes) return the Concrete Strategy class?
What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: That's what I would do. What is your doubt?

Comment: TBH, it sounds like a non-OO maintenance nightmare to have the factory use "is-parameter-set" heuristics to guess which strategy to use. What if you end up with two strategies that use the exact same parameters? You won't be able to use this factory design.

Comment: If they have the same parameters set, it should be the same strategy returned.

Comment: So you're basically saying that the retrieval strategy is defined by which combination of parameters are set, so the scenario I mentioned can't happen, by assumption?

Comment: That is what I am saying, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the return value in the method signature should be the common interface or base class.

The factory must have the if tests to decide on the concrete type to return, but that's unavoidable, unless you can craft a Map that returns a concrete instance based on a composite key class that encapsulates parameter combinations.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, `RetrievalStrategyFactory`, where to begin? This sounds like overengineering for a [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI). One approach is create an enum for specifying the "set" field, assuming there's one retrieval strategy per parameter, and use that as the factory.

```
public enum FieldParameter {
    LIMIT {
        RetrievalStrategy getRetrivalStrategy(int value) {
            return new LimitRetrievalStrategy(value);
        }
    },
    SPEED {
        RetrievalStrategy getRetrivalStrategy(int value) {
            return new SpeedRetrievalStrategy(value);
        }
    };

    abstract RetrievalStrategy getRetrivalStrategy(int value);
}
```

Then the client code is not explicitly specifying the retrieval strategy, but it is implicitly given when the client code informs your code which field the user provided.

Comment: There might be more than one value, a strategy may need many parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ability to extend a factory it you want an Abstract Factory. This is a factory of Factories. An Abstract Factory can have many plugin factories, which can follow a strategy to determine which factory is used.

This is usually needlessly complicated and something you can add later, so its not something you need to do just in case you might need it.